# Como encontrar a posição de elementos iguais em vetores de caracteres (character)?

Tags: r

Considerando:

```
a<-c("Ano", "X2751006.", "X2751007.", "X2751008.", "X2751015.", 
     "X2751017.", "X2751018.", "X2751025.", "X2752001.", "X2752006.", 
     "X2752007.", "X2752008.", "X2752009.", "X2752010.", "X2752011.", 
     "X2752012.", "X2752013.", "X2752014.", "X2752017.", "X2752021.", 
     "X2753001.", "X2753002.", "X2753003.", "X2753004.", "X2753005.", 
     "X2753007.", "X2753008.", "X2753009.", "X2753014.")

 b<-c( "X2752013.", "X2752014.","X2753014.")
```

Qual a função que devo aplicar para saber qual é a posição do itens de `b`
em `a`, utilizando R?

OBS: Apliquei a função `which` e `grep` e não tive sucesso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se tu busca elementos em `a` que são **exatamente** iguais aos elementos em `b`, a melhor opção é usar `%in%`:

```
a<-c("Ano", "X2751006.", "X2751007.", "X2751008.", "X2751015.", 
     "X2751017.", "X2751018.", "X2751025.", "X2752001.", "X2752006.", 
     "X2752007.", "X2752008.", "X2752009.", "X2752010.", "X2752011.", 
     "X2752012.", "X2752013.", "X2752014.", "X2752017.", "X2752021.", 
     "X2753001.", "X2753002.", "X2753003.", "X2753004.", "X2753005.", 
     "X2753007.", "X2753008.", "X2753009.", "X2753014.")

 b<-c( "X2752013.", "X2752014.","X2753014.")

a %in% b
which(a %in% b)
```

Se quiser buscar por expressões regulares, uma opção é combinar `mapply()`, `grepl()`, `apply()` e `unlist()`:

```
apply(unlist(mapply(grepl, a, MoreArgs = list(b))), 1, which)
```